# Inserting a Row in a Table from Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using two Stored Procedures and two Table in My Sql Server.

First Table Structure.

[image]

Second Table Structure.

[image]

When a Customer books a Order then the Data will be Inserted in Table 1.

I'm using a Select Query in another Page Which Selects the Details from the Second Table.

If a row with a billno from first table is not Present in Second Table I want to Insert into the Second Table with some Default Values in the Select Query. How can I do this
??

Comment: Do you want this row with default values to actually be inserted into the second table, or just for the query to return a row *as if* it existed in the second table? If the second, we'd need to see your current query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is to `LEFT JOIN` the two tables and then select only the ones where the second table had no row to join, meaning the bill number were missing. 
In the example below, you can replace `@default_inform_status` and @default_response_status with your default values.

```
INSERT INTO second_table (Bill_Number, Rest_Inform_Status, Rest_Response_Status)
SELECT ft.Bill_Number, @default_inform_status, @default_response_status
FROM first_table ft
LEFT JOIN second_table st
  ON st.Bill_Number = ft.Bill_number
WHERE st.Bill_Number IS NULL
```

If it is possible to have duplicates of the same `Bill_Number` in the first table, you should also add a `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`. But considering the fact that it is a primary key, this is no issue for you.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me Perfectly. Since the Bill_number in First Table is a Primary key there is no necessity to use `DISTINCT`.
Anyway Thank you.

Comment: Just a comment on my answer: This will check the entire `first_table` for missing  bill numbers which might be a heavy query if the tables are large and the second table is not indexed on `Bill_number`. Adrian's solution only checks the Bill_number just being inserted which might be a kinder way to treat your database.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to insert in the same query, you will have to create a stored procedure. There you'll query if row exists in second table, and, if not, insert a new entity in second table.

Your code should look something like this:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`table`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertBill`(IN billNo int, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalres INT DEFAULT 0;
     select count(*) from SECOND_TABLE where Bill_Number = billNo INTO totalres;
        IF totalres < 1 THEN
            INSERT into SECOND_TABLE values(val1,val2,val3);
        END IF;
END
```

Val1,val2 and val3 are the valuest to be inserted into second table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the good answer effort as novice Stack Over Flow User.

Comment: Thank you but I'm novice in SQL Server so I did not understand your Answer!

Comment: @Krishna Thota It's ok. Now I saw that the images are from Microsoft SQL, not from MySql (for which my code is). Stored Procedures are a series of sql queries which allows you to have variables, IF-ELSE clause and so one.   You can find examples and turorials here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [link](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=9129)

Comment: Thanks for the kind info. but I know about stored procedures but I didn't understand the `DEFINER=`table`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertBill` part in your code

Comment: CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])
    [characteristic ...] routine_body. Where DEFINE is used for checking access privileges, and insertBill is the procedure name. Hope now is ok.